# Getting all events for a user using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Calling the api like this, I only get events the user is attending.

```
        FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath("/me/events")
```

And this makes sense according to the docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/)

> Events for this person. By default this does not include events the person has declined or not replied to

But how do I chance this to include the events the person "has declined or not replied to"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do it in one call, but you can do it with three:

```
/me/events (gets "attending" and "maybe" events)
/me/events/declined (gets "declined" events)
/me/events/not_replied (gets "not_replied" events)
```

I'm still trying to find an option to do it in one call, but this is the fallback I'm using for now.

Answer (score 1):

There is no endpoint for that in the Graph API as far as I know. It was possible with FQL though, but if your app is v2.1 or higher you can't use FQL anymore.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/